# Sharepoint: Can I embed a non-Sharepoint site into Sharepoint as a stand-alone site?

Tags: html, css, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

My agency uses Sharepoint (SP) to create and host websites for various other offices within the agency.

I recently built a non-SP site using CSS/HTML and was wondering if there was a way to get that site into SP and have it "qualify" as a SP site. In other words, is there some kind of SP wrapper that I would place around my HTML code? A way to embed the site? iFrame?  I guess I am looking for a way to get around the requirement that all office websites need to be created in SP...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a PageViewer web part which you can find under Media and Content

[image]

Then udpate the Web Page property to your website address.  This would work like iframe

[image]

Comment: This looks good. Are there any examples on the web of live sites doing this?

Comment: You dont need samples its really straightforward doing it.  I suggest you create a Test Team Site and do it there

Comment: I want to test this on my home computer. I'm confused as to what version to download for the PC. I tried to download the 2010 ersion and it said I needed Windows Server 2008 to run it. Help!